# Alternative to .Equals() when passing in a null value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I have this method, it checks if the property has changed but when a null value is passed in it falls over with an Object Reference not set to an instance error due to the .Equals method.

```
public bool HasPropertyChanged(string property, object newValue) {
    bool result = false;

    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = Entity.GetType().GetProperty(property);
    if (!newValue.Equals(propertyInfo.GetValue(Entity, null))) {
        result = true;
    }

    return result;      
}
```

This is the solution I've came up with for the issue but I was hoping to do something a bit cleaner I looked into using ReferenceEquals() but it always returns false when a value is passed in. Any tips/advice would be great.

```
public bool HasPropertyChanged(string property, object newValue) {
    bool result = false;
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = Entity.GetType().GetProperty(property);
    object oldValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(Entity, null);


    if (newValue != null) { 
        //check to prevent Object Reference not equal to null
        if (!newValue.Equals(oldValue)) {
            result = true;
        }
    }
    else if (oldValue != null) { 
       // If oldValue is not null then return the property has changed
        result = true;
    }
    return result;  
}
```

Comment: Use object.Equals(obj1, obj2) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Object.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) static method which takes care of the `null` objects.

```
public bool HasPropertyChanged(string property, object newValue) 
{
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = Entity.GetType().GetProperty(property);
    return !object.Equals(newValue,propertyInfo.GetValue(Entity, null));
}
```

Comment: @grimmeld Intuitively two null values means that value has not been changed right. This method will return false only. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @grimmeld Did you try it? I guess you overlooked the `!` operator before `object.Equals`

Answer (score 1):

If using Entity Framework which it looks as though you might be.... try something like the following:

```
if (Entity.State == EntityState.Modified)
{

}
```